# Wait for element to change then bind a click event

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, click

I'm trying to detect when the text of a hyperlink changes (based on a javascript function I have no control over).

When the text changes to 'Unlike', I want to attach the click event. For the purpose of simplifying this question, all I need is to detect when the text has been changed to 'Unlike'. I'm am trying the following but it fires before the text change:

```
$("a:contains('Like')").click(function(){LikeClick($(this))});

function LikeClick() {

    $("#" + ths[0].id + ":contains('Unlike')").ready(function(){
        alert('the text has been changed')
        //Attach click event to all like buttons
    });
}
```

Here is the original element:

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="likesElement-1" class="ms-secondaryCommandLink">Like</a>
```

Comment: `ready` doesn't do what you think it does. Also your code has syntax error and how does "JS finish"?

Comment: Fixed the syntax error. The script finishes by changing the innertext to 'Unlike'

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$('.like').on('click', function(){
   //whatever you want the code to do on a like. 
   //If it has a callback function wrap the code below in that.
   this.removeClass('like');
   this.addClass('unlike');
   this.text("Unlike");
});

$('.unlike').on('click', function(){
   // unlike code goes here. Same as before with callback.
   this.removeClass('unlike');
   this.addClass('like');
   this.text("Like");
});
```

Just add the `like` class on your like links/buttons. You might need to add [prevent default](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to the beginning of those functions.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I have the exact ID though and I only want to target one element and listen for its text to change. I will try this with the ID selector

Comment: This didn't work for me. All I want to do is basically have an alert when the text changes to Unlike

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a simpler solution to your problem:

```
$('.theButton').on('click',function(){

    //Toggle the 'like' class on each click, then look for the class
    if($(this).hasClass('like')){
        $(this).removeClass('like').addClass('unlike');
        likeClick();
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('unlike').addClass('like');
        unlikeClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to change the class of the button, I'm trying to detect when the text is changed by a script that I have no control over. I modified the question, hopefully my goal is clear. thx